# Submitting a form to Rails with ReactJS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs

I'm trying to submit a simple form to my Rails app. I lost myself in confusion and nothing's working. This is what I have tried to do:

```
var newUserForm = React.createClass({
  propTypes: {
    user: React.PropTypes.array
  },
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {name: '', age: '', country: '' };
  },
  handleNameChange: function(e) {
    this.setState({ name: e.target.value });
  },
  handleAgeChange: function(e) {
    this.setState({ age: e.target.value });
  },
  handleCountryChange: function(e) {
    this.setState({ country: e.target.value });
  },
  handleSubmit: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var name = this.state.name.trim();
    var age = this.state.age.trim();
    var country = this.state.country.trim();
    if (!name || !age || !country) {
      return;
    }
    this.setState({ name: '', age: '', country: '' });

    var user = {user: this.state.user}
    this.setState({data: user});
    $.ajax({
      url: '/users/new',
      dataType: 'json',
      type: 'POST',
      data: {user: user},
      success: function(data) {
        this.setState({data: user});
      }.bind(this),
      error: function(xhr, status, err) {
        this.setState({data: user});
       console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
      }.bind(this)
    });
  },


  render: function() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={ this.handleSubmit }>
        <input type="text" placeholder="User's name" value={ this.state.name } onChange={ this.handleNameChange } />
        <input type="text" placeholder="His age" value={ this.state.age } onChange={ this.handleAgeChange } />
        <input type="text" placeholder="Country of origin" value={ this.state.country } onChange={ this.handleCountryChange } />

        <input type="submit" value="Post"/>
      </form>
    )
  }
});
```

And my console:
[image]

I need some help.

## toy_controller.rb

```
class ToyController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @users = User.all
    render component: 'usersList', props: { users: @users }
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
    render component: 'newUserForm'
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)

    if @user.save
      render component: 'showUser', props: {user: @user }
    else
      render text: "Something went wrong."
    end
  end

  private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :age, :country)
  end
end
```

## routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get '/users', to: 'toy#index'
  get '/users/new', to: 'toy#new'
  post '/users/new', to: 'toy#create'
end
```

Comment: Are you using server side rendering for React? Where are you mounting the component? The error is saying that you're rendering into an element that already has markup, and it doesn't match the markup that React generated when running `render` the first time. Rendering into an empty element like `<div></div>` will prevent this error.

Comment: You have both `user` and `users` variables, what is the expected values of these?

Comment: I haven't used Rails in a decade, but shouldn't you include the user object in a property called 'user' in order to send it as JSON? (i.e. `data: { user: user },`)

Comment: Can you please post your log (placed in `log/development.log`)? Because we don't know what's causing `BadRequest` in Rails.

Answer (score 4):

**TL;DR:** you most likely just need to restructure the JSON you are sending to include the 'user' key

---

### lengthier response:

you are using what are called 'strong params', so when you call `user_params` in `#create` and have `require(:user)`, if the params hash does not have the word `user` as a key, the error you see above is raised.

one route would be to restructure the data you are sending to include the word 'user'

for instance:

`{user: {name: 'test', age: 1}}`

so maybe (could modify however you'd like to achieve the above structure)

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/users/new',
  dataType: 'json',
  type: 'POST',
  data: user,
  success: function(data) {
    this.setState({data: user});
  }.bind(this),
  error: function(xhr, status, err) {
    //this.setState({data: user});
    // console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
  }.bind(this)
});
```

to

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/users/new',
  dataType: 'json',
  type: 'POST',
  data: {user: user},
  success: function(data) {
    this.setState({data: user});
  }.bind(this),
  error: function(xhr, status, err) {
    //this.setState({data: user});
    // console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
  }.bind(this)
});
```

Comment: @siaw23 wanna try out what I had written and see what happens?

Comment: Specifically `var user = this.state.user;` should likely be `var user = {user: this.state.user};`. I'd also then change the name to `userData` as it's more indicative of what's inside it.

Comment: i'm updated my post as per your suggestion. you can see the new error in the console. also i'm not sure if the routes.rb file makes any sense.

Comment: @siaw23, thank you! before you send the JSON client-side could you print it out and tell me what the response is? i.e. console.log(user)

Comment: @siaw23 also, typically to create a resource, the url would be '/resource' in your case and using POST as opposed to get (as you had done), but of course feel free to map the urls however you'd like my good sir!

Comment: i get "Uncaught ReferenceError: user is not defined".

Comment: @siaw23 gotcha. wanna try printing it out right after where you had defined it? (after where you had written 'var user ...'

Comment: ah right! i didn't it wrongly `Object {user: undefined}` :)

Comment: @siaw23, where you already have the user key, defined where your setting the variable (var user = ...) you wouldn't need to add an additional key in the ajax call and could rewrite it to the way you had had it. wanna try that and then see what happens?

Comment: like just pass the `user` in the ajax right? yes. i did that, no luck. same error

Comment: you got it. also, an additional step (see where user is showing as undefined?), would want to ensure your data is structured similar to the example I had given in my post, really you could just put that code directly, wanna try that and see if it works, and then could go about ensuring your data is structured correctly from there?

Comment: @siaw2 may want to have a look at this.state.user, I think it may be undefined

Comment: that makes sense. i see it now. `user` is not defined anywhere.i'm not sure how and where to do that. maybe in the `getInitialState` method?